# python code to read registry

Tags: python, registry

```
from  _winreg import *
areg=ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
akey=OpenKey(areg,"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
"""for i in range (259):"""
subkey=EnumKey(akey,0)
print subkey
demo=[]
demo=QueryValueEx(akey,"")
print demo
```

i am trying to obtain the value within the subkey ,what is wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

```
akey=OpenKey(areg,"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
```

with

```
akey=OpenKey(areg,r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")
```